# When is 分 read ぶ instead of ぶん

Tags: words

I had always thought that when you were talking about percentage, fractions, portions, etc., it was always pronounced **ぶん**. However, I saw its pronunciation listed as **ぶ** on [Imabi](http://www.imabi.net/numbersix.htm), a renowned website for self-learners.  The likelihood of its being an error was rather low, since the author seemed to really know his stuff, solid.

On Imabi, a couple of examples were given:

> 五分五分{ごぶごぶ}の確率
>   九分九厘{くぶくりん}勝てる。
>   *八九分{はっくぶ}

*Strangely, MS-IME does not show **八九分** for **はっくぶ**, I have to type each kanji separately. Could it be due to its not being an idiom?

The first two seem to be 四字熟語, so I would simply assume the pronunciations are not up for discussion. However, what about other combinations, such as **九割九分**? According to this [native speaker](https://www.reddit.com/r/LearnJapanese/comments/3odrpj/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%84%E3%83%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC_shitsumonday_for_the_little_questions_that/) (ID: ywja):

> It's either きゅうわりきゅうぶ or くわりくぶ. Personally, I find that きゅうわりきゅうぶ is more common. Also, it sounds more colloquial and casual to my ears, probably because きゅう sounds more casual than く as the reading of 九.

**Question #1.**
Her/his explanation appears not to be about personal preference, or regional/dialectic difference. If there is indeed room for variation, as this person suggests, what are some common examples (other than **九**) where multiple readings apply for the sake of nuances? For instance, for **四分**, what are the possible readings? `よぶ, よんぶ, and/or しぶ?` In addition, how does one read `何分, 一分, 三分, 八分, 十分, 百分`, and so on?

---

Unfortunately, that is not all.

First of all, as far as I know, **分** should be read as **ぶん** for fractions, such as **三分{さんぶん}の一{いち}**. The same goes for portions, such as **千人分の生ビール**, or **三十年分のビール**.

Next, I looked up **分** again in a dictionary, and for this specific pronunciation, **ぶ**, *研究社* listed only one English translation, **"percent."** The following are all the sample sentences provided:

> 1. 銀行は 4 *分の利子で金を貸してくれた。 The bank lent me the money at 4 percent interest.
> 2. 日本チームに*分がある勝ちそうだ。 The Japanese team is likely to win.
> 3. 今回は我々のほうが*分がいい。 We have an advantage this time.
> 4. その仕事は 9 *分どおり済んだ。 The work is 90 percent done.

For 2. & 3., I think **ぶ** is the only possible reading, since only under **ぶ** is this meaning listed. In *goo辞書*, 1st entry under **分（ぶ）**:

> どちらに傾くかの度合い。自分のほうに有利になる度合い。

**Question #2.**
For 1. & 4., can you read it as **ぶん** as well? Moreover, shouldn't it be **9 percent** in 4., or **九割**?

---

Again, under **割（り）（わり）**, *goo辞書* has this definition：

> 2. 歩合の単位。1割は10分の1。

And for **分（ぶ）**:

> 5. 全体を10等分したもの。10分の1相当の量。
> 6. 単位の名。㋐割合・利率で、1割の10分の1。全体の100分の1。

I guess one does not simply consult a dictionary, and go "Eureka!"

**Question 3.**
How does one decide, then, when **（一）分** means **one-tenth**, but not **one-hundredth**? Moreover, how does one read it? **ぶ**, or **ぶん**?

長文ですみません… いつも迷惑をかけてばかりんですが…どうぞよろしくお願いいたします！

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**A1:** When 分 means 10%, 一分 ～ 九分 is usually read like いちぶ, にぶ, さんぶ, よんぶ, ごぶ, ろくぶ, ななぶ/しちぶ, はちぶ, きゅうぶ/くぶ. But 九分九厘 is an idiom that is always pronounced くぶくりん. 九割九分 is usually きゅうわりきゅうぶ, but くわりくぶ may not be wrong. 何分 is なんぶ.

**A2:** These are read as 4分【ぶ】の利子, 分【ぶ】がある, 分【ぶ】がいい, 9分【ぶ】どおり. No exceptions. その仕事は9分どおり済んだ and その仕事は9割済んだ effectively mean the same thing, 90%. See below.

**A3:** 分 read as ぶ **essentially means 10%**, not 1%. However, 分 **appears to mean 1%** if it follows 割, which is another term meaning 10%.

割 means "10% of the entire fraction". 分 on its own works like 割, but 分 also works somewhat like the SI prefix *deci-*; it's used in combination with another unit and refers to one tenth of it. For example, 一寸五分 (いっすんごぶ) means 1.5 [sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cun_(unit)) (≒4.5 cm), and 37度5分 (さんじゅうななどごぶ) means 37.5 ℃. Likewise, when 割 and 分 are used together, 2割5分 means "2.5割", which is 25%. This explains why both 九割九分 and 九分九厘 mean 99%.

That being said, for historical reasons, 分 means 1% even without 割 in financial contexts and baseball contexts. 4分 (よんぶ) automatically means 4% when you are talking about interest rates and batting averages. Outside of these types of situations, you can assume that 分 read as ぶ means 10% (cf 四分咲き → 40%, 七分袖 → 70%, 五分五分 → fifty-fifty).

[image]

You seem to correctly understand how to read 3分【ぶん】の1, 30年【ねん】分【ぶん】のビール, 2時30分【ぷん】, and so on, so I won't go into detail about them.